# Msft MRTK3 on Unity for HoloLens 2 - Object Manipulator feature overrides button clickable/pressable functions. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to design a UI panel using MRKT3 for the HoloLens 2. It is a panel with pressable buttons. Anytime I add object manipulator script (to make panel grabbable, interactable, etc.) this unfortunately seems to make my buttons no longer clickable.

How can i go about this?

[Inspector with Object Manipulator included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQOh.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the issue reported, what is likely happening is the button is getting the parent attributes applied via inheritance.  From the image, one cannot see the code or relationship but that is what sounds like in the post.

If you have the pressable button to be the parent and underlying objects under it, that should work.